# not appending duplicates in list -python

Tags: python, duplicates, append

My code is:

```
for datum in data :
        sick.append(datum[2])
```

and result is

```
sick=['J02', 'J02', 'J20', 'J20', 'J20', 'J20', 'J20', 'A08', 'J45','A08']
```

what I want is

```
if sick[i] == sick[i+1], don't appned value
```

so result  I want is

```
sick=['J02', 'J20', 'A08', 'J45','A08'] <-- this isn't removing duplicates. I just don't want to append "if sick[i] == sick[i+1]"
```

what should I do?

Comment: `from collections import OrderedDict; sick = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(datum[2] for datum in data))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If duplicates should be allowed then this would work:

```
for datum in data:
    if len(sick) == 0 or sick[-1] != datum:
        sick.append(datum)
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
for datum in data :
    if not datum in sick:
        sick.append(datum)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following

```
data = ['J02', 'J02', 'J20', 'J20', 'J20', 'J20', 'J20', 'A08', 'J45']
sick=[]

for datum in data:
    if datum not in data:
       sick.append(datum)
```

This will give the output:

```
['J02', 'J20', 'A08', 'J45']
```